# Example website login/registration code?

Tags: asp.net, authentication, user-registration

I am looking at building the login/registration part of a website (ASP.NET) and would like to see some example code or instructions on how to do this properly. For example, how to correctly use cookies and how to encrypt what is stored in the cookie to ensure the session persists until they logout/timeout.

I do not want to use the builtin ASP.NET Membership/Provider stuff as it looks painful to use and not very flexible. Please do not answer with 'This is how easy the ASP.NET Membership/Providre stuff is to use, just check this out and you will use it!' as I don't want to use it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't get me wrong, I'm just wondering what exactly do you find painful and not flexible about the ASP.NET providers? I've used them a lot and I find them very flexible. I've even written some custom providers which is a straight forward process.

If you don't want to use ASP.NET providers, what are your exact requirements? I might help you out if I understand a bit better what you are trying to achieve.

Michael

Comment: I want the user to login with an email/password pair and not using a username/password. This reduces the amount of information they have to remember to login. 

The provider implementation only give username/password as the parameters to use for validation.

Comment: When someone registers using an email address/password combo, I would immediately email that address for confirmation it is valid and expect them to click a link to confirm it. Even better, I could get a new user to provide only an email address to register and then email them their password for subsequent use. That reduces registration to just 1 field. Much better chances of getting them to do that.

Comment: You could achive the former by having the email address act as username. In this case you might use a custom wizard for registration but you can still take advantage of the rest of provider implementation such as cookie handling, persistence...

Regarding having only an email field to register, I personally find that anoying if I then have to go back to my email to find a password that I for sure not like just to login and have to change it. Do you know what I mean?

Comment: If you still want to go down the path of implementing a complete custom solution you may want to have a look at how the providers are implemented (e.g. using Reflector).
I haven't done custom logins since .NET 2.0 came out. However, I might find an example from prior 2.0 if you are interested.

Comment: If you find anything that would be great. Thanks.